# Joomla Ajax loading for contact form component

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I am trying to implement ajax loading for the joomla 3.2.1 default contact form component.

I set a menu link to the contact form in the backend.

This is the HTML output :

```
<nav id="menu2">
    <div class="moduletable">
        <ul class="nav menu">
            <li class="item-138"><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and I have this div at the bottom of the page :

```
<section id="contact_form">
</section>
```

I implemented this Jquery code :

```
$('.item-138 a').click(function () {
    $('#contact_form').load("index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=1&tmpl=component")
    return false;
});
```

The contact form loads well and my template override works. but **how can I prevent loading the `<head>` content that comes with it?**

The `<title>` tag, default scripts (mootools jquery...) and default css ( `/templates/system/css/general.css`, `/templates/system/css/template.css`)

Can I do that with a template override? Is it even possibler?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent the `<head>` being loaded. The scrips and css files that get pushed into the head ceom from different extensions such as your template, a plugin, module, component etc etc.

Comment: I would like to control these assets and prevent loading twice js scripts and css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is this value that you attach to the get request.

`&format=raw`

so your request looks like

```
index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=1&tmpl=component&format=raw
```

also you may want to make a copy of your `view.html.php` and rename it `view.raw.php`

Comment: This works well but I would like to understand how it works, what is the use of the `view.raw.php` file? Will it be deleted if I make an update?

Comment: well if its a custom component, then there's nothing to worry about, but if its core or third party component and you wish to update after customizing then ...maybe you have something. 

what the format=raw argument does, is that it tells the Joomla! to send just the bare-bone output generated by a view/controller to the client (instead of appending all the template and the modules etc.)

There are other types of output overrides like 

   format=pdf etc.

You could just read about those in Joomla! Official Documentation.

Comment: The Pleasure is all mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load part of the page you want from the load, something like this.

```
$('#contact_form').load('index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=1&tmpl=component #formID');
```

Check this documentation for Loading Page Fragments [here.](http://api.jquery.com/load/)